# C# Selecting a Query from a ListBox

Tags: c#

I have a ListBox FILLED with IDs + Employees. They're all listed as: ID  -  Employee Name.

Now, I want to make a Select Query with the Selected ID. But if I do, it will select ID + Employee Name = Crash. How can I "trim" it somehow so I can only get the ID? Thanks.

Comment: `Split()` would be your best bet here. Can you provide an example of your `ID - Employee Name` combination? Is the ID a fixed length?

Comment: string.Split('separator') is what you need, Drew already answered you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Split()` method is likely the best way to achieve what it is you're looking to accomplish.

Say for example you had a String value for your `ID - Employee Name` combination as follows:

```
String listIndexValue = "0AB456MyID01 - John Doe";
```

You can use the following to retrieve the ID with:

```
String id = listIndexValue.Split('-')[0].Trim();
```

This would return: `0AB456MyID01`.

The `Split()` method returns an array of String values based on where your original String is split. In this case, there are two values returned, `0AB456MyID01` and `John Doe` (whitespaces included). Obviously arrays have indexes, and since we only wish to retrieve one value, we call for `0AB456MyID01`, or index 0. `Trim()` obviously will remove the trailing whitespace in `0AB456MyID01`.

Comment: @user4136548 if this worked accept the answer to mark the question finished ! You can do it from green mark !